# UK TV show about clone on the run

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was a kids TV show in the UK that ran in the late 2000s.

**Basic plot:** a secret cloning facility of male teen clones with two different colored eyes, one clone escapes and finds a girl who helps him. They both have to go on the run when the people at the cloning facility try to track him down and take him back.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When you say "two different colored eyes" do you mean that each clone had mismatched eyes, or do you mean that some clones had one color and others had a different one?  Was this an animated show?  Why don't you check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and see if there are any other details that come to mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be [*The Fugitives*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fugitives_(TV_series))

It was on CITV from April to May 2005. The main plot as follows seems to match your description:

> Twelve-year-old Jay Keaton's life is in grave danger, he stumbles across a shocking discovery at the company his father used to work at. He and his friend Mel are on the run from the corrupt cloning company EmbroGen! The two children are on a dangerous mission to stop EmbroGen and reveal them for what they really are.

J2 who is the clone of the main character Jay has one green eye and one blue.